# node redis - id generation race condition

Tags: node.js, redis, transactions

Multiple processes have access to my redis store. When adding a new *user* hash, I do the following steps:

1. incr userId
2. set user:[the incremented userId] ...

How can I bundle these steps into a transaction?

```
const client = require('redis').createClient();

client.on("connect", () => {
    const multi = client.multi();
    multi.incr("userId", (userId) => {
        console.log("new userId is %s", userId);    // TODO userId should not be null
        multi.set("user:"+userId, {name:"UserName"} );
    });
    multi.exec();    // TODO after the execution I expect to see the key user:null using redis-cli, but it does not exist
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a the reply from an operation on a transaction inside the same transaction, but there's also no need for that in your case - the `INCR` operation is atomic and guaranteed to return a race-free unique value.